# ANTLR3: Ensuring that character occurs in at least one place

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I am trying to ensure that at least one character is included in the text with wildcards

```
fragment CHARACTER : ('a'..'z'|'0'..'9'|'-'|'&'|'@'|'$'|'%'|'.'|':'); 
fragment WILDCARD_QUESTION  : ('?'); 

WILD_STRING 
   : (CHARACTER)* 
     ( 
       (WILDCARD_QUESTION) 
       (CHARACTER)* 
     )+;
```

Using this even a single ? gets accepted where as I would like it to fail. So only sequences that that at least one character should be passed.

What I need is for `a?`, `?a`, `?a?`, `a?a` etc to pass. Only `?`, `??` etc should fail. ie there should be at least one character and not just WILDCARD_QUESTION. The character can be on either side of the wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with two rules, one for leading WILDCARDs and one for leading CHARACTERs:

```
WILD_STRING : (WILDCARD_QUESTION)+ CHARACTER (CHARACTER | WILDCARD_QUESTION)*
            | (CHARACTER)+ WILDCARD_QUESTION (CHARACTER | WILDCARD_QUESTION)*
            ;
```

Comment: Tried your solution in antlrWorks and it breaks w??m?n into a partial entry after the first ? where as my solution below does not do that. I may still be wrong but it seems to do the job I want. Need to test further

Comment: I'm pretty sure that both solutions match the same way. You can use each of it ... but in _my_ opinion my solution is a bit more clear ;).

Comment: Agreed. I felt the same thing and was even going to approve your answer. But when I checked in AntlrWorks, these differences came up. Perhaps you can check and confirm ?

Answer (score 0):

Changed code to read

```
    WILD_STRING 
       : (((WILDCARD_QUESTION)+(CHARACTER))|((CHARACTER)+(WILDCARD_QUESTION)))
(WILDCARD_QUESTION|CHARACTER)*
       ;
```

This seems to solve the issue.